# Why is information_schema.columns not working?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I've loaded (example) data into my workspace using:

```py
import pandas as pd
table_name = pd.read_csv("data/name.csv", index_col=0)
table_name
```

To begin the process of cleaning any errors in the data, I've followed with SQL code:

```sql
SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'table_name'
```

I'm expecting:
|column_name|data_type|
|-----------|---------|
|column_name|int      |

However, I get this instead:

| 0 rows |
| --- |

I've been able to use successfully information_schema.colummns when the database has already been loaded into the workspace and I have not had to import pandas to then download the dataset. Is that why I get the 0 rows result? If so, what better approach could I take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means your `table_name` has not yet been created in your server. You'll need to do your `CREATE TABLE table_name ...` operation first.

And, you should add `AND SCHEMA_NAME = DATABASE()` to your where clause. It's possible for a server to contain multiple tables with the same name in difference databases.